# Jquery align container tables of the page

Tags: jquery, html, css, css-selectors

I have an HTML page that has many nested tables, for example table for header and table for content and another for footer, and each table has some child tables

the problems is that I don't have access to tables to give them IDs or Classes, I can only attach JavaScript or css file to the page (because it's based on oracle portal) the page is full width, all tables take 100% width,

I want to re-size the tables ( the parents only) to be 1020px width, without touching those tables, only with jquery or css

so i did that

```
$('body > table').width(1030); 
$('body > table').css('margin','0 auto');
```

the width is corrected alright and the tables are centered on the screen, but the tables are now aligned to left on internet explorer that means `.css('margin','0 auto');`  is not working on internet explorer...

any suggestion ?

Answer (score 0):

Do it all with jQuery like this:

```
$('body > table').css({'width':'1020px', 'margin':'0px auto 0px auto'});
```

Your first jQuery line seems like it could be setting the width attribute of the table, not the CSS width property.

Comment: Ok, can you try one more thing? Set the body to be `text-align:center` then set all the tables to `text-align:left`

Comment: not working also in internet explorer, by the way it's internet explorer 8